# div height same size as table content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div1 next to another div2 that contains a table.  This table is dynamically created and at times becomes longer than div1.  How can I dynamically change the height of div1 based on the number of elements of the table in div2 using javascript?

Comment: Please consider providing code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onresize = (() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#div1').css(
      'height',
      document.querySelector('#div2').offsetHeight + 1
    )
  }, 10);
});
$('#div1').css(
  'height',
  document.querySelector('#div2').offsetHeight
)
```

```css
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 16px);
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id = 'div1'>hello world</div>
  <div id = 'div2'>
    <!--copied from
    https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro-->
    <table border = '2'>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The only problem here is that You have to re-resize #div1 when the content or styles of #div2 change because I don't know how to do that. I think you just need to hardcode it cause I tried adding a 'resize' event listener to #div2 and it didn't work